# NPM install hangs when installing packages

Tags: angular, npm, rxjs, npm-install, npm-scripts

I currently using a project. It works fine but the problem when I remove the project files(except `node_modules`) to another folder or GitHub, reinstalling packages via npm is not successful. It always hangs at

> `extract:rxjs: sill extract big.js@3.1.3`

I tried `npm cache verify` no luck.

Here is `packages.json`

```json
{
  "name": "esas",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "angular2-loaders-css": "^1.0.9",
    "angular2-perfect-scrollbar": "^2.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

I am using:

- Windows 10
- Node version: 8.50

Any ideas what is wrong?
Kind Regards

Comment: given git link shows pagenotfound

Comment: Hi Vino. Already solved problem. Remove package-lock.json and node-modules. Then run npm install again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved problem by

1. Remove `package-lock.json`
2. Remove `node_modules` folder
3. Run `npm install` again. (took 30 minutes to finish but finally did)

Comment: I know this is old, but I just want to point out what works for me.

If above steps does not work,
1. Try placing your package-lock.json into the folder again,
2. Run npm install

Works for me in less than 3 minutes.

Comment: Other solutions on the web did not work for me. This did. Thanks Vugar.

Comment: 30 minutes is a very long time for "npm install"-- this does not seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Once one of packages seemed to be stuck. I just needed to wait for 15 minutes and it completed.

Comment: Yes, that is my exact experience too. It just gets stuck for a very long time and then proceeds just fine. I am using an internal `npm registry` so that probably has an impact too. My guess is that it may be timing out when attempting to get that package, but does it silently. The weird thing is that it does output a 200 status after everything so I am at a loss here.

Comment: Why is the answer saying look at Andrey's answer have more upvotes than Andrey's answer?

Answer (score 3):

I think Andrey's answer is correct. No error is thrown and it appears to just hang, but while searching for the fix the package finally downloaded and the install process completed. Probably took about 7-8 minutes. Maybe specific to the rxjs package? But I wouldn't recommend removing the `package-lock.json` file as the fix. You could try deleting your `/node_modules` folder if it exists already.

Answer (score 0):

So for me this looks to be an issue with the global Angular cache getting messed up or something. I ran into this switching from a branch that we are working on upgrading to Angular 15 (the Material changes have made it hard for us to migrate) to an Angular 14 branch to fix a bug for our client, whenever I switch I noticed that installing Angular Material and RxJS will freeze the install and then eventually break the window I'm running the command in. I usually have to run these steps to get it fixed:

1. Remove package-lock.json
2. Remove node_modules folder
3. Remove the .angular/cache folder (if found)
4. Run npm install

If that doesn't work, then I try restarting my computer. Usually this works but then causes those two packages to take 3-5 minutes each to install. If that doesn't work then I've had to clear the global angular cache (which I do not recommend) but then it usually runs the install like normal afterwards.